Recently purchased an apartment and noticed this on my balcony wall
What is this at the base of my balcony wall?




the pics you posted do not work.  Use the mountains and moon icon to add pics to your question.

I've edited to make actual links out of your images, then attempted to use the built in hosting system (which is always preferred), however, the thumbnails that are linked are considered too small to be posted. Please [edit] your question again, then use the "sun & mountain" icon to embed full size copies of your images in the question itself. Using BB-Code to embed images doesn't work here as this site doesn't use BB-code

What is the wall made of?  Concrete?  wood?  It looks like there was water damage from rain on the balcony floor, but that is just a guess. It could be primarily cosmetic or something more serious depending on the material used in the construction of the wall.

It's not at all clear what you're asking about here. Please take properly exposed photos and describe more clearly your concern. All I see is some forming or troweling ripples in what's either plaster or concrete.

Thanks all greatly appreciated.
Freeman - thanks for fixing the links.
RMDman - The wall is made of concrete I believe. Does that mean it’s likely a cosmetic issue?

There;s also some dirt there. A brush and soapy water should address that.

@Nick,  what you are seeing is cosmetic.

This looks like a poured concrete wall, and the marks look like the imprint or 'ghosting' left from the plywood used to make the forms. The plywood was probably left outside for too long, got wet and delaminated, leaving that imprint on the concrete.

Image from https://basc.pnnl.gov/

If you really care, you can grind it flat and repaint it.  I wouldn't bother.

Thanks Cheery! Much appreciated! I believe it is a poured concrete wall. The straightness of the lines did make me think it was a man-made issue rather than water damage. Don’t often get lines that straight in nature…

Thanks gbronner- agreed.

@Nick It is water damage, but to the forms, not the concrete. It will have no effect, except cosmetic.

@Nick -- think of it as a bit of character ;) its not like buildings aren't allowed to have that any longer

@Cheery thanks again that is very much appreciated!

@ThreePhaseEel Haha. Indeed!
